# Is it possible to intercept add/remove methods on a generic list using postsharp?

Tags: c#, validation, aop, postsharp

I am new to AOP and post sharp (2.1.0.0). I have been experimenting with property/method interception and am able to write inteceptor aspects for classes which I have written.

My goal is to not have lists with any logic in them before compile time.

An example of what I want to achieve is:

```
public class Foo
{
    //Implementation should throw an exception if more than 1 string added.
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

One thing I am not sure about are lists. I want to be able to run some validation when either Add() or Remove() is called on a list. I think I can do this if I wrap the list in my own custom list class and decorate the class with the aspect attribute.

I know I can accomplish this using my own custom list and do something clever in my own implementations of Add/Remove - but this is what I would prefer to avoid if possible.

Is there any other (or a better) way of intercepting these methods - specifically using post sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a collection changed event for a generic List in .NET. I know you don't want to hear this, but you either need to wrap List or you need to create a class that implements IList.

Comment: Thats cool - I only wanted to avoid it if at all possible. I know you can hook into events using postsharp (but haven't explored that yet) - so if I had a list that did raise events, do you know if it would be preferable to write aspects to get those events, or just write aspects to intercept the add/remove?

Comment: I would write the class, implement IList and have a backing list to store the items in (to make it simple). You can then implement INotifyCollectionChanged and raise the event when an add/remove/clear is performed. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668629.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to modify the `List<T>` class in this way because the `Add` method is not virtual. If the `MyList` property returned an `IList<string>` instead, then the object returned by it could perform this type of validation.

The .NET framework provides the [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) class to help you extend certain list functionality. The easiest way to implement the feature you describe is deriving a class from it and perform the validation in [`InsertItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132412.aspx).

The `Collection<T>` class implements `IList<string>`, so you'll still need to change the property type of `Foo.MyList`.

**Edit for AOP:** If you wanted to use AOP for this feature, instead of returning a list from `MyList` that the user manipulates, the `Foo` class would provide `Add` and `Remove` methods that performed the necessary validation before making changes to a backing list. In this case I would return `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` from the `MyList` property to make it clear that the list is only manipulated via methods provided in `Foo`.

Comment: I can subclass List<T> and declare an implementation of add() using the 'new' keyword. This does my validation - and if the validation passes it calls base.add(). It's a little bit nasty but it works. That wasn't really what I was asking tho.

Comment: @Jay No, it does not work. It's important to understand this or you'll have a very hard time tracking down inevitable problems if you try it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626049/overriding-listts-add

Comment: Good point - thanks for the link, I think I'll just go with wrapping the List<T> and applying my aspects to the wrapped version.