# c# list property Add method extra action

Tags: c#, list, properties, addition

i have a list property like that

```
protected IList<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors;    
public IList<System.Windows.Media.Color> Colors
{
     get { return colors; }
     set { colors = value; }
}
```

and i have a function

```
protected void updateBuffers()
```

which needs to be called each time a property user change the property, for example

```
Colors.Add(...)
...
Colors.Clear(...)
```

is there an elegent simple way to do that?

Comment: You wanto call the function everytime your colors change?

Comment: I will point you, When object is added to a list, the function .Add is running for the collection, you should override it, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626049/overriding-listts-add

Comment: Try making a Customized Generic method of List.Add method which inputs the list as parameter and after that run your desired method i.e updateBufffers(). for e.g
ListAdd(Colors);
public void ListAdd(IList List){
List.Add(..);
updateBuffers();
}

Comment: Don't use List<>, you cannot override its methods.  The best class to use is `Collection<T>`.  Works just like List<> but it has protected methods you can use to detect items getting added or modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot with a plain list.
You can however create your own class implementing `IList<T>` or inherit from `Collection<T>`.

Or you can use an `ObservableCollection<T>` or any built-in class implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms668604.aspx) for documentation.

Moreover, ObservableCollection will allow you to use your collection in bindings if you are using them for populating UI in WPF or Windows 8 applications.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new object that created additional properties, using the List as a base class:

```
public class CustomList<T> : List<T>
{
    public new void Add(T item) {
        base.Add(item);
        this.UpdateBuffers();
    }
}
```

The 'new' keyword is required to completely overwrite the existing implementation of Add, which isn't marked as `virtual` in the base class.

Thanks to Hans Passant and LarsTech for their feedback in the comments.

Comment: Please use a C# compiler to test your code before you post it.  You'll discover the very basic flaw in your answer, the List<>.Add() method is not virtual so cannot be overridden.

Comment: Hmya, that doesn't work either of course.  The client programmer will just use Add() as normal, or use the IList methods, and it will fail to work in a completely undiagnosable way.  You've got the answer with the most votes, it's your burden to make it a useful answer :)  At least talk about the Collection<> class.  Or delete your answer.

Comment: @HansPassant this makes you wonder about the whole vote system

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't `public new void Add(T item) {...}` work?

Comment: @Lars - no, still fails miserably when the client programmer uses an IList reference to the collection.  It will call the hidden method.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah, had a feeling I was missing something.