# How can I handle adding of the items, defined in XAML, when application starts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the next problem.

I have a type, like Fooo : List, and I fill this collection from XAML. Is it possible to override "add" methods at List<> (Add, AddRange, Insert, etc) in Fooo, in order to implement some "add logic" (e.g. if item with some property exist - throw exception)? I'm trying to redefine "add" methods at List (using "new" keyword, but it doesn't work).

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. As noted below, you can't override the methods. The best you can do is _hide_ the `Add()` method by using `new` in the method declaration. But code that doesn't view the object as your `Fooo` type won't get the method; it's generally bad to hide members (which is why C# forces you to be explicit when you do). It's not clear why you want to override the adding process; you can implement `IList` yourself instead of inheriting `List<T>`, but why not just not add wrong elements in the first place. What's the actual scenario here? See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to override "add" methods at List<> (Add, AddRange, Insert, etc) in Fooo

No, you can't. We should encapsulate `List<T>` and implement [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx)

There are some questions talking about this:

- [How do I override List<T>'s Add method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580202/how-do-i-override-listts-add-method-in-c)
- [Overriding List<T>'s Add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626049/overriding-listts-add)

Comment: Ok, if I have implemented Fooo, XAML must invoke methods to add items from Fooo, not List<>, right? Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @slavka In xaml, you should fill the List<T> and it will call Add method to append new item to the list. Implementing the List<T> interface is the right way